# Facebook Website Custom Audiences: Multiple URLs?

Tags: facebook, target-audience

Is it possible to create a custom audience based off of multiple different URLs? For example- We sell tickets to events. Certain events use 1 shopping cart system, while others use another. Hence, they have different URLs.

I would like to create a Custom Audience for anyone who has made a purchase to ANY event from either of the 2 URLs. It's a perfect solution for an 'OR' operator, but there's only option for an 'AND'.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use combinations of logical operands now either by clicking the "and" button (for adding an "and" condition , obvious) or by clicking the "Add New Condition" button (for adding an "or" condition).

Maybe this functionality wasn't available a year ago when you posted your question, but I believe you can close it solved by now :)

[image: Facebook Custom Audience Logical Operands]